# Fast conversion of large (2.1gb+) binary file (lat/long/altitude to ECEF)

Tags: python, performance, file, io

Right now, I'm trying to convert a large quantity of binary files of points in latitude longitude altitude format to text based ECEF cartesian format (x, y, z). The problem right now is that the process is very very very slow.

I have over 100 gigabytes of this stuff to run through, and more data could be coming in. I would like to make this bit of code as fast as possible.

Right now my code looks something like this:

```
import mmap
import sys
import struct
import time

pointSize = 41

def getArguments():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print """Not enough arguments.
        example:
            python tllargbin_reader.py input_filename.tllargbin output_filename
        """
        return None
    else:
        return sys.argv

print getArguments()

def read_tllargbin(filename, outputCallback):
    f = open(filename, "r+")
    map = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0)
    t = time.clock()
    if (map.size() % pointSize) != 0:
        print "File size not aligned."
        #return
    for i in xrange(0,map.size(),pointSize):
        data_list = struct.unpack('=4d9B',map[i:i+pointSize])
        writeStr = formatString(data_list)
        if i % (41*1000) == 0:
            print "%d/%d points processed" % (i,map.size())
    print "Time elapsed: %f" % (time.clock() - t)
    map.close()


def generate_write_xyz(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'w', 128*1024)
    def write_xyz(writeStr):
        f.write(writeStr)
    return write_xyz

def formatString(data_list):
    return "%f %f %f" % (data_list[1], data_list[2],data_list[3])
args = getArguments()
if args != None:
    read_tllargbin(args[1],generate_write_xyz("out.xyz"))
```

convertXYZ() is basically the conversion formula here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_system

I was wondering if it would be faster to read things in chunks of ~4MB with one thread, put them in a bounded buffer, have a different thread for conversion to string format, and have a final thread write the string back into a file on a different harddisk. I might be jumping the gun though...

I'm using python right now for testing, but I wouldn't be opposed to switching if I can work through these files faster.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

**EDIT:**

I have profiled the code with cProfile again and this time split the string format and the io. It seems I'm actually being killed by the string format... Here's the profiler report

```
         20010155 function calls in 548.993 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  548.993  548.993 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.016    0.016  548.991  548.991 tllargbin_reader.py:1(<module>)
        1   24.018   24.018  548.955  548.955 tllargbin_reader.py:20(read_tllargbin)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.020    0.020 tllargbin_reader.py:36(generate_write_xyz)
 10000068  517.233    0.000  517.233    0.000 tllargbin_reader.py:42(formatString)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 tllargbin_reader.py:8(getArguments)
 10000068    6.684    0.000    6.684    0.000 {_struct.unpack}
        1    0.002    0.002  548.993  548.993 {execfile}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.065    0.065    0.065    0.065 {method 'close' of 'mmap.mmap' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'fileno' of 'file' objects}
    10003    0.955    0.000    0.955    0.000 {method 'size' of 'mmap.mmap' objects}
        2    0.020    0.010    0.020    0.010 {open}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.clock}
```

Is there a faster way to format strings?

Comment: Have you profiled the code to find out what part is slow?

Comment: If you have a few computers at your office not doing anything over night, perhaps you could consider hadoop? http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/  Hopefully it wont have to come to this though

Comment: What if you change the `write` calls to just `f.write("some_string_of_about_the_length_of_your_numbers")` so you can see how much of that time is the string formatting?

Comment: Then the whole routine is around 50 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To more precisely attack the problem, I suggest measuring the file read operation by making 'convertXYZ' a no-op function and timing the result.  And measuring the convert function, by changing the 'read' to always return a simple point, but calling the conversion and output the same number of times as if you were really reading the file.  (And probably another run where the final post-conversion output is a no-op.)  Depending on where the time is going, it may make a lot more sense to attack one or the other.

You might be able to get the local OS to do some interleaving for you by writing the output to the Python's stdout, and having the shell do the actual file IO.  And similarly by streaming the file into stdin (e.g., `cat oldformat | python conversion.py > outputfile`)

What sort of storage are the input and output files on?  The storage characteristics may have a lot more to do with the performance than the Python code.

Update: Given the output is the slowest, and your storage is pretty slow and shared between both reads and writes, try adding some buffering.  From [the python doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) you should be able to add some buffering by adding a third argument to the `os.open` call.  Try something pretty large like 128*1024?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

I actually have the convertXYZ as a noOp right now (it just returns the first three doubles. On a small 400MB file, it's currently running at around 10 minutes per file, or around 682.666667 kBps.

The storage format is an ordinary 7200 RPM internal SATA2 drive.

Comment: I checked the profiler again, and split the write function into string format and the write. It seems I'm actually being killed by the string format... Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: Wow, I reproduced the format-is-slow locally.  I'm not sure if its the formatting or the new-string alloc-and-GC that kills this.  I don't see anything like Java's 'StringBuffer' for Python that might help isolate the GC effects.  Might be worth asking a more focused SO question?  (Or try re-writing this in Perl or Java or C?)

Comment: Yeah I'm not too sure what is happening when using string format. I actually managed to achieve a 10x speed up by switching to pypy. I'm guessing it compiled the format loop into something more manageable. thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Given that `formatString` is the slowest operation, try this:

```
def formatString(data_list):
    return " ".join((str(data_list[1]), str(data_list[2]), str(data_list[3])))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tested it out, but it seems to be just as slow, if not slower than the % format.

Answer (score 0):

2.1 GB of data should take between 21 (@ 100 MB/s) to 70 (@ 30 MB/s) seconds just to read. You're then formatting that into and writing data which is perhaps five times as large. This means a total of 13 GB to read and write requiring 130-420 seconds.

Your sampling shows that reading takes 24 seconds. Writing should therefore require about two minutes. The reading and writing times can be improved using an SSD for example.

When I convert files (using programs I write in C) I assume that a conversion should take no more time than it takes to read the data itself, a lot less is usually possible. Overlapped reads and writes can also reduce the I/O time. I write my own custom formatting routines since printf is usually far too slow.

How much is 24 seconds? On a modern CPU at least 40 billion instructions. That means that in that time you can process every single byte of data with at least 19 instructions. Easily doable for a C program but not for an interpreted language (Python, Java, C#, VB).

Your 525 second processing (549-24) remainder indicates that Python is spending at least 875 billion instructions processing or 415 instructions per byte of data read. That comes out to 22 to 1: a not uncommon ratio between interpreted and compiled languages. A well-constructed C program should be down around ten instructions per byte or less.